# How do i get the selected row data in phprunner printer-friendly event?

Tags: php, xampp, lamp

How do i get the selected(clicked) data details in the printer-friendly event in the `php runner`:

```
BeforeMoveNextPrint($data, $row, $record, $recordId, $pageObject).
```

I tried using `$data` and got only the first row of the table. I am not able to use `$record` or `$row`. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you provide more source details? Possibly the `BeforeMoveNextPrint` function.

Comment: @PS1212 Something like this
//$barcode = $data["BarCode"];
//header("Location: barcode.php?f=png&s=code-39-ascii&d=".$barcode)